# Can raspberry pi 4 B boot from 256 GB SSD that uses USB adapter?

Tags: raspbian, usb, usb-power

I installed raspbian on the Samsung Evo 860 256GB SSD. The SATA adapter and did not power up when I plugged it into the raspberry USB port. I think that its the power supply. Raspberry 4 B may not have enough power on the port to run the boot. The drive draws about 100 mA of current. Raspberry Pi 4 B,  has 3.0A PSU current capacity, 1.2A peripheral current draw, active current consumption 600mA. I guess that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: what research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

At this time (April 2020) the answer is a qualified NO.

Unlike some of the earlier Pi boards, the Pi 4 cannot directly boot from SSD yet (it has been promised but no date set) so you have to use a hybrid by putting part of the OS on the SD card and some on the SSD.

Two main threads on the Pi support forums cover this:

1. A 23 page locked thread starting [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=243995) goes through the history and pains
2. A 10 page thread starting [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=196778) that covers the work around using RonR’s (a user on the forums) solution.

Reading through these will show you how to configure the SD card and SSD to get the best of the bad mess RPF/RPT left the boot capability in or you can download and use the usb-boot script to do it for you.

I will say I have not used the script and would recommend you check what it does and try it on a test set-up before using it live.

RonR does help folk with issues on the forum BUT rightly expects them to test / try things as part of debugging and feed back accurately.  (i.e. It’s your computer and call to use the software, I cannot help if it does not work).

Comment: *by putting part of the OS on the SD card and some on the SSD* - to be clear, the boot partition on the sdcard, and the root will be on the SSD - sounds daunting the way you put it - the operating system is ALL on the SSD, what's on the SD is the boot partition, which includes the kernels and overlays etc :p